# I can't access my Python scripts using the Atom editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

Trying to execute 1.py and 2.py scripts which are saved in my .atom folder.

However when I copy exactly what my tutorial video types I get errors (shown in screenshot). Also the atom tutorial doesn't seem to work for me either.

Tried creating a 3.py file in the user1 directory so I could access directly but all I get is a quick flash of a pop up window and then nothing.

[image: atom screenshot]

Comment: It will be helpful for future reference if you add the error message from the picture to your post as a text. Otherwise it is hard to find using a search engine.

Comment: What about `python 3.py`?

Comment: The term '.\' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Che
ck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ .\ <<<<  .atom
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: python 3.py gives similar error: The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: 1. from the picture one cannot see where `3.py` resides, it might not be in the user1 dir, 2. to execute python scripts you need to call the binary `python` or `python2` or `python3` if they are on the path (google environment variable path) or you need to call them from where they are (pseudo example: `C:\Program Files\PythonXYZ\bin\python3`)

Answer (score 0):

First, python should be in the [PATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables).

Then, inside powershell, if you're in "C:\Users\user1" you should be able to launch:

```
python 3.py
```

and see something, as long as `3.py` exists and prints something.

One alternative would be to install [script package](https://atom.io/packages/script). Then `CTRL+ALT+B` will launch the script directly. You'd still need to install python and have it in PATH.

If you still have problems, read this [page](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex0.html) (learnpythonthehardway.org) very carefully. Don't jump any step, and you should be fine.